# MySQL Table Summary Cascade

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers, structure, cascade

I'm designing a statistics tracking system for a sales organization that manages 300+ remote sales locations around the world.  The system receives daily reports on sales figures (raw dollar values, and info-stats such as how many of X item were sold, etc.).

I'm using MAMP to build the system.

I'm planning on storing these figures in one MySQL big table, so each row is one day's statistics from one location.  Here is a sample:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
| LocationID | Date | Sales$ | Item1Sold | Item2Sold | Item3Sold |
------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hawaii     | 3/4  | 100    | 2         | 3         | 4         |
| Turkey     | 3/4  | 200    | 1         | 5         | 9         |
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Because the organization will potentially receive a statistics update from each of 300 locations on a daily basis, I am estimating that within a month the table will have 9,000 records and within a year around 108,000.  MySQL table partitioning based on the year should therefore keep queries in the 100,000 record range, which I think will allow steady performance over time.

(If anyone sees a problem with the theories in my above 'background data', feel free to mention them as I have no experience with building a large-scale database and this was simply what I have gathered with searching around the net.)

---

Now, on the front end of this system, it is web-based and has a primary focus on PHP.  I plan on using the YUI framework I found online to display graph information.

What the organization needs to see is daily/weekly graphs of the sales figures of their remote locations, and whatever 'breakdown' statistics such as items sold (so you can "drill down" into a monetary graph and see what percentage of that income came from item X).

So if I have the statistics by LocationID, it's a fairly simple matter to organize this information by continent.  If the system needs to display a graph of the sales figures for all locations in Europe, I can do a Query that JOINs a Dimension Table for the LocationID that gives its "continent" category and thereby sum (by date) all of those figures and display them on the graph.  Or, to display weekly information, sum all of the daily reports in a given week and return them to my JS graph object as a JSON array, voila.  Pretty simple stuff as far as I can see.

Now, my thought was to create "summary" tables of these common queries.  When the user wants to pull up the last 3 months of sales for Africa, and the query has to go all the way down to the daily level and with various WHERE and JOIN clauses, sum up the appropriate LocationID's figures on a weekly basis, and then display to the user...well it just seemed more efficient to have a less granular table.  Such a table would need to be automatically updated by new daily reports into the main table.

Here's the sort of hierarchy of data that would then need to exist:

1) Daily Figures by Location
2) Daily Figures by Continent based on Daily Figures by Location
3) Daily Figures for Planet based on Daily Figures by Continent

4) Weekly Figures by Location based on Daily Figures by Location
5) Weekly Figures By Continent based on Weekly Figures by Location
6) Weekly Figures for Planet based on Weekly Figures by Continent

So we have a kind of tree here, with the most granular information at the bottom (in one table, admittedly) and a series of less and less granular tables so that it is easier to fetch the data for long-term queries (partitioning the Daily Figures table by year will be useless if it receives queries for 3 years of weekly figures for the planet).

Now, first question: is this necessary at all?  Is there a better way to achieve broad-scale query efficiency in the scenario I'm describing?

---

Assuming that there is no particularly better way to do this, how to go about this?

I discovered MySQL Triggers, which to me would seem capable of 'cascading the updates' as it were.  After an INSERT into the Daily Figures table, a trigger could theoretically read the information of the inserted record and, based on its values, call an UPDATE on the appropriate record of the higher-level table.  I.e., $100 made in Georgia on April 12th would prompt the United States table's 'April 10th-April 17th' record to UPDATE with a SUM of all of the daily records in that range, which would of course see the newly entered $100 and the new value would be correct.

Okay, so that's theoretically possible, but it seems too hard-coded.  I want to build the system so that the organization can add/remove locations and set which continent they are in, which would mean that the triggers would have to be reconfigured to include that LocationID.  The inability to make multiple triggers for a given command and table means that I would have to either store the trigger data separately or extract it from the trigger object, and then parse in/out the particular rule being added or removed, or keep an external array that I handled with PHP before this step, or...basically, a ton of annoying work.

While MySQL triggers initially seemed like my salvation, the more I look into how tricky it will be to implement them in the way that I need the more it seems like I am *totally* off the mark in how I am going about this, so I wanted to get some feedback from more experienced database people.

---

While I would appreciate intelligent answers with technical advice on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do, I will more deeply appreciate wise answers that explain the correct action (even if it's what I'm doing) and why it is correct.

Comment: Will the reports be generated as a scheduled process, or during interactive sessions?  If the former, then performance is much less of an issue; even if the latter, (depending on other server load) aggregating such data from the raw data should be perfectly acceptable provided that adequate indexes have been defined.  Why not fill your proposed structure with dummy data and benchmark the results?

Comment: @eggyal I was planning on generating them on the fly. You make a good point on scheduled vs. on-demand. I suppose a decent compromise would be to make them scheduled, since the data is entered once a day, with the ability for a user to manually initiate a "recount". I will investigate indexing thoroughly, and try benchmarking.  Thank you.  :)